# Reusing Nodes in implementation of a Decision Tree

Tags: c++

I saw this Decision Tree implementation in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgwfCyQSbs4&ab_channel=ProfesorRetroman) stream (is in spanish).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Node {
    virtual void run() noexcept = 0;
    virtual ~Node() noexcept = default;
};

struct ActionSay_t : Node {
    explicit ActionSay_t(std::string&& w) : 
        what { std::move(w) } {}
    void run() noexcept override {
        std::cout << this->what << "\n";
    }
    std::string what;
};

struct DoThingsIf : Node {
    //El orden es importante!
    explicit DoThingsIf(bool condition, Node& y, Node& n, std::string id) :
        why{ condition }, yes{ y }, no{ n }, id{ std::move(id) } {}
    void run() noexcept override { 
        std::cout << id << "\n";
        why ? yes.run() : no.run(); 
    }
    bool why;
    Node& yes;
    Node& no;
    std::string id;
};

struct DecisionTree_t {
    //Utilizamos esto para gestionar los unique_ptr
    using NodeStorage_t = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>>;
    explicit DecisionTree_t(std::size_t reserve_nodes_n = 1) {
        nodes.reserve(reserve_nodes_n);
    }
    void run() noexcept {
        if (nodes.size() > 0) {
            nodes[0]->run();
        }
    }
    void addNode(std::unique_ptr<Node>&& node) {
        this->nodes.push_back(std::move(node));
    }

    NodeStorage_t nodes;
};

DecisionTree_t
createTree() {
    //optimización del valor de retorno -> t no desaparece del ámbito ni se copia, se crea
    //en el contexto que le llame
    DecisionTree_t t{ 6 };
    auto helloNode   = std::make_unique<ActionSay_t>("Hola!");
    auto byeNode     = std::make_unique<ActionSay_t>("Bye!");
    auto haltNode    = std::make_unique<ActionSay_t>("Halting!");
    auto doNode      = std::make_unique<DoThingsIf>(true, *helloNode, *byeNode, "doing_Second");
    auto firstDoNode = std::make_unique<DoThingsIf>(true, *doNode, *haltNode, "doing_first");
    auto last        = std::make_unique<DoThingsIf>(true, *firstDoNode, *haltNode, "doing_flast");

    //Hay que añadir todos los nodos por la gestion del unique_ptr
    t.addNode(std::move(last));
    t.addNode(std::move(firstDoNode));
    t.addNode(std::move(doNode));
    t.addNode(std::move(helloNode));
    t.addNode(std::move(byeNode));
    t.addNode(std::move(haltNode));

    return t;
}


int main() {
    DecisionTree_t t = createTree();
    t.run();
}
```

However, I'm noticing that `createTree` has some problems. First of all, using `std::make_unique` and later passing the nodes with `std::move` seems dangerous, because after passing them to `addNode` we're going to have some `nullptr` there.

Because of that, we can't reuse the nodes. So let's say that we want to have some branches, like

```
  if current_hour % 2 == 0
      /                   \
  if current_day == 31    say bye
  /        \
say hi    say bye
```

With this implementation, we would need to have 2 nodes for bye, because of that `std::move`.
Is there any good way to get rid of this problem?

Comment: You can use `std::shared_ptr<>`?

Comment: If performance is relevant and the tree logic is quite "internal", don't use `std::shared_ptr<>` (can even become an issue for cyclic references...). A way to go here might be to simply refer to raw pointers for the nodes and to store the actual ownership information via a linear container of `std::unique_ptr<>` s top-level-side.

Comment: Hm, after re-reading your code, I guess the existing approach is almost doing what I described and what you want to achieve. Could you please provide a piece of actual code that is supposed to be dangerous due to the nullptr-possibiltiy? Just to be clear for me that I really adress your actual problem.

Comment: @Secundi the problem that I see it has to do more with the fact that we're losing the reference to the nodes, so we can not reuse them. Imagine a bigger tree, with some sub-trees repeating. Making it would be a pain.

Comment: The issue is: you do not store references to unique pointers, you store references to nodes. That's why I'd like to see your code that you suppose to be invalid at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because of that, we can't reuse the nodes.

You cannot use the unique pointers to the nodes for another tree or in general after they are moved, that's clear. But you can still refer to the underlying allocated memory that is not(!) affected by the move operation on the unique pointers.

So for instance, this is totally well-defined:

```
auto someString = std::make_unique<std::string>("Some string");
const auto& someStringContent = *someString;
auto moveConstructedString = std::move(someString);

// This will still print "someStringContent: Some string
std::cout << "someStringContent: " << someStringContent;
```

The plain data reference is still valid here. It must, since this is one major guarantee of shared and unique pointers (at least to stay consistent to the construction via an already existing raw pointer for instance). Instead of references, even raw pointers would persist in a valid way here.

The algorithm you provided is IMO actually exactly doing what you want. It ensures the top-level storage of the nodes with

```
t.addNode(std::move(node));
```

guaranteeing a proper well-ordered clean up for the destruction case of the tree. If you want to refer to already used nodes afterwards, simply refer to their raw pointers or references to the underlying data that you obtained before the adding to the tree.